# how to use Slice function for json format in ruby?

Tags: ruby

```
{
  "Message": "Action completed. Completed the Request. One or more of the subsequent operations did not succeed. Please check the logs.",
  "Details": null
}
```

from the above json response i want to print only "Action completed. Completed the Request"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many different ways to do this...

One of them is:

1. split the message data sentences (split)
2. get the two first items from split ([0..1])
3. join them back with a dot (join("."))

split the message data sentences, using the dots as separator:

```rb
require "json"
payload = '{
  "Message": "Action completed. Completed the Request. One or more of the subsequent operations did not succeed. Please check the logs.",
  "Details": null
}'
data = JSON.parse(payload)
puts data["Message"].split(".")[0..1].join(".") # "Action completed. Completed the Request"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach using the `slice` function as mentioned in the question. I've used a regexp match to extract the part of the string interesting for you.

```rb
require "json"

data = JSON.parse('{
  "Message": "Action completed. Completed the Request. One or more of the subsequent operations did not succeed. Please check the logs.",
  "Details": null
}')

res = payload.inject('') { |r, (k, v)| r = v.slice(/^.+\..*\./) if k == :Message; r }

#  => "Action completed. Completed the request."
```

As @andredurao said, there are multiple ways to achieve it and `slice` is not the only one.